# Mysqli query doesn't execute

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm here with a "strange" problem.

This is how i create a new topic. 
If sesson isnt set go back to index.php, or if is set it connects to db, get informations from form and put them into db. Then if is all ok browser go back to index.php. This works fine:

```
<?php 
    session_start();

    if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
        header("location: index.php");
    }

    if(isset($_POST["submit"])){

        include ('../modules/dbconnect.php');

        $uname = $_SESSION['username'];
        $utitle = $_POST["title"];
        $utext = $_POST["myTextArea"];

        $query = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO topic (author, title, text) VALUES ('$uname', '$utitle','$utext')");

        if($query){header("Location: ../index.php");}

        $conn->close();
    }
?>

<form class="registration_form" action="" method="post">
    <label>Titolo</label>
    <input type="text" name="title" class="input">
    <label>Testo</label>
    <textarea name="myTextArea"></textarea>
    <input class="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

And this is my problem. I've used the same structure to insert post after i enter into a topic but i don't know why this doesnt work and i can't figure out what's the problem:

```
 <?php
      if(isset($_POST["submit"])){

         include('modules/dbconnect.php');

         $id = $_GET['id'];
         $uname = $_SESSION['username'];
         $utext = $_POST["myText"];

         $query = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO post (id, author, text) VALUES ('$id, '$uname', '$utext')");

         if($query){header("Location: ../index.php");}

         $conn->close();
     }
 ?>

 <form class="reply_form" action="" method="post">
     <label>Testo</label>
     <textarea name="myText"></textarea>
     <input class="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
 </form>
```

Comment: print $conn, and check DB is connected or not.

Comment: *"doesn't work"* ...it helps if you provide more information about what actually doesn't work, or what happens.

Comment: `echo $query;` and what do you get?

Comment: Missing `'` at `('$id, ..`. Better use prepare statement.

Comment: Neeraj - I've aleady do that with if ($conn->connect_error) { etc..

BadHorsie - the "post_maker.php" doesnt execute mysqli_query

user51 - print author and text

Saty - actually while is was modifying my code i've deleted this ' but seems thats not the problem...

Comment: Thank you all for the help, i'm gonna try to fix this using prepare statement as Saty said ^^

Comment: Off-topic: Typo

Answer (score 1):

```
VALUES ('$id, '$uname', '$utext')
```

--> Missing a ' after $id ???

Answer (score 1):

In first working code snippet ,
include ('../modules/dbconnect.php');

and below you used 
include('modules/dbconnect.php');

so it may be chances that you have no connection object due to file path issue.
please check with it
and if any error you seen than post error here

Comment: Yeah because this two php files are created in 2 different directories.

Comment: If not done yet than simply set error_reporting(E_ALL).
it would be helpful you to trace the exact error.

and yes,Instead of $utext = $_POST["myText"];
prefer to use $utext = addslashes($_POST["myText"]);

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
  $query = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO post (id, author, text) VALUES ('$id, '$uname', '$utext')");
```

To this:

```
  $query = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO post (id, author, text) VALUES ('$id', '$uname', '$utext')");
```

Also the check for the correct path of `include('modules/dbconnect.php');` as you've used two different paths  `include('../modules/dbconnect.php');` at first and the other one next.

Missing `'` at `('$id,`

Answer (score 0):

Are you using InnoDB as storage engine? If so, maybe you forgot to either set [`mysqli_autocommit`](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.autocommit.php) to true or call [`mysqli_commit`](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.commit.php) after your query.